# Inverse proportionality graph

Tags: graphing-functions

This question has been bothering me from many days. If I wanted to represent the graph of $xy =$ constant, why does the graph of $xy=$ constant come out to be a curve , something like this ? 
[image: xy = 5]

$xy=$ constant means that $x$ is inversely proportional to $y$ and as $x$ increases $y$ decreases and vice versa. 
But the same thing is also indicated in the following graph right ? 
[image]

In this graph also , we see that as $x$ increases $y$ decreases. Then why is the graph of inverse proportionality always a curve ? I’m sorry if this question sound really elementary, but this has been bothering me from many days

Comment: slope is not same at all points for $xy=c$

Comment: @Abhishek how do we arrive at that conclusion ?

Comment: for 2nd graph: we can get $x+y=c$ $\implies$ slope will be $-1$ at every point. But for first? Simply these are two different things.

Comment: @Abhishek thank you , but is there a method to show that the graph of $xy=c$ is not constant ? Or is it not possible to find out the slope of the graph itself ?

Comment: it is simple just look at the graph...otherwise you can check it by putting values of x.

Comment: @Abhishek alright thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we give a closer look we will firstly get 2 different equations for the different curves,
[[1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBAvA.jpg) this curve gives us $$xy = 5 $$
and,

[[2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeV4C.png) this curve gives us $$x+y = 9$$
now,plotting a graph is basically seeing how the dependent variable (usually $y$) varies with the independent variable (usually $x$).
So, we can see that in [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBAvA.jpg)] the equation loosely transforms to $y =\frac{5}{x}$ , and in [[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeV4C.png)] we have $y=9-x$.
Now, as we have 2 different functions for the 2 different equations [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBAvA.jpg)] and [[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeV4C.png)] we can actually compare as [@Abhishek](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/516174/abhishek) pointed out, the slopes of these two functions at each point and see that they are not the same.
Which boils the argument down to the rate of change of $y$'s with the respective $x$'s which hence gives us a curve and a straight line.